# .NET solution to create a slowed down playback rate MP3, with pitch preservation

Tags: .net, audio-recording, audio-processing

I have a working solution partly in .NET that takes an MP3 file (vocal audio) and saves a version of the MP3 at a slowed playback rate, while preserving pitch. I have found a solution that does preserve pitch somewhat, although the audio fidelity is not as good. Are there other solutions out there that require fewer components to accomplish what I'm doing, and are there solutions that preserve pitch while retaining a higher level of audio fidelity?

I am looking at fewer moving parts for greater scalability.

At this time I'm using nAudio to convert the MP3 to Wav, then SoundTouch to slow the playback rate of the Wav, then LAME to encode the Wav back to MP3.

Thanks
Shan

Comment: By *slowing down*, do you mean playing it back at a slower rate (like playing a vinyl at slower speed which results in the pitch going down) or actually slowing it down *with* pitch preservation? The first task isn't hard if you can decode your audio. The second one was enough for me to write a thesis on in uni, and it still only scratched the surface.

Comment: The latter, with pitch preservation. There are some commercial audio effects packages on the market for musicians that are able to do this reasonably well. I finally ran into SoundTouch which is able to do this somewhat well, http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/soundstretch.html#examples. I think that it does this by estimating the tempo of the audio. For non-rhythmic audio such as spoken vocals, the library doesn't seem to be as effective

Comment: I've updated my question to reflect this, thanks for asking

Answer (score 2):

Generally it's not possible to operate on MP3 without decoding-encoding pipeline. LAME btw can do decoding too.

Comment: Thanks re the lame to Wav decoding note